# JsonUtility is throwing exception when there is \" in the string

Tags: unity, json

The following is my JSON file:

```
{
    "data" : [
               {
                 "nameString" : "My name is \"Ansar\"",
                 "id" : 1234
               } 
    ]
}
```

When I try to parse this JSON file using **JsonUtility**, it is throwing an exception because of the **\"** character. If I remove the character from the string, it works smoothly.

**Exception**:

```
ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Missing a comma or '}' after an object member.
UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:50)
```

Why this is happening? Is this a **JsonUtility** bug? Anyways to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The `"nameString" : "My name is \"Ansar\""` should be kept as `"nameString" : "My name is \\\"Ansar\\\""`. That is *Backslash* is replaced with \\ .

Resource: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1638/)